# Spam blacklisting monitoring

Tags: spam, blacklist, monitoring

I own a store and have a bunch of affiliates who promote it, for an affiliate fee.
Lately I encountered situations where affiliates spam via email, getting my store domain name blacklisted, usually only a few days down the road.
Is there a good blacklisting monitoring tool, both for MX records and for spam DB's?
I'd be happy to pay for a quality service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Doubtless there are others, but I recommend [HTTP:BL](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl.php), which uses blacklist data compiled by [Project Honeypot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/index.php). There are easy-to-use plugins for a lot of common CMSs.

It can be used for free if you set up a "honey pot" (a trap which reports spambots) on your site. For certain commercial and high-traffic applications, you need to contact them.

> All active members of Project Honey Pot may use the basic http:BL service for free. To qualify as "active," merely install a honey pot, add a QuickLink to your site, donate an MX entry, or refer some friends to the Project. If you qualify, you can request an Access Key for http:BL.